# Drawing a Hasse diagram for Cartesian poset

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Lets define B={3,6,9} and A=BxB. On poset A we define relation ~ with: 
(a1,b1)~(a2,b2) <=> (a1|a2) AND (b1<=b2)

I am really stuck with drawing incidence matrix for cartesian poset. I understand it when it is being done for poset on the N, Z or other set of numbers. Since I cannot review if I did the assignment on a good way, I would really appreciate if someone can write matrix and draw hasse. I need to review it. I am studying for an exam.

My matrix looks like this:

```
     (3,3)  (3,6)  (3,9)  (6,9)  (3,6,9)
```

(3,3)      1      1      1      1       1

(3,6)      0      1      1      1       1

(3,9)      0      0      1      1       0

(6,9)      0      0      0      1       0

(3,6,9)    0      1      1      1       1

Did I write it good? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should consider is "what are the elements of $A$?" Based on the matrix you've given, it looks like you only have 5 elements of $A$, when in fact there are 9 (also you've listed $(3, 6, 9)$ as an element of $A$ when it is not). If you're studying for an exam, definitely review the definition of a Cartesian product of two sets.

For completeness, the 9 elements of $A$ are $(3, 3)$, $(3, 6)$, $(3, 9)$, $(6, 3)$, $(6, 6)$, $(6, 9)$, $(9, 3)$, $(9, 6)$, and $(9, 9)$.

The adjacency matrix is then as follows:

$$\begin{array}{r|c c c c c c c c c}
\sim & (3, 3) & (3, 6) & (3, 9) & (6, 3) & (6, 6) & (6, 9) & (9, 3) & (9, 6) & (9, 9) \\ \hline
(3, 3) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
(3, 6) & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
(3, 9) & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
(6, 3) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
(6, 6) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
(6, 9) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
(9, 3) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
(9, 6) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
(9, 9) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}$$

A Hasse diagram might then look like the following:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
(6, 9) & & & & (9, 9) \\
\uparrow & \nwarrow  & & \nearrow & \uparrow \\
(6, 6) & & (3, 9) & & (9, 6) \\
\uparrow & \nwarrow & \uparrow & \nearrow & \uparrow \\
(6, 3) & & (3, 6) & & (9, 3) \\
& \nwarrow & \uparrow & \nearrow & \\
& & (3, 3) & &
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks mate! :)
But one question -> I didn't add some items because I felt like it is not needed. 
Why? Because if it is equivalence relation. So if a~b then b~a. So I meant it is being common sense. Am I wrong? Should I always add both (3,6) and (6,3) in Hasse even though I am doing equivalence relation?
On the other hand, yeah adding (3,6,9) was much bigger mistake.
Anyway thank you for your time! This helped me :)

Comment: Is it an equivalence relation though?  Double check that.  In particular, the element (3,6) is not an element of the relation, but an element of A.  The relation is then a subset of A x A.  In particular, if a relation is symmetric, then the adjacency matrix should be itself symmetric, whereas in this case it is not.